# ValueError: No references to stock.report_picking_list in Openerp

Tags: python, odoo

I get the following error when i update my openerp-server6.0.I work on Opensuse OS any help?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./openerp-server.py", line 121, in <module>
db,pool = pooler.get_db_and_pool(dbname, update_module=tools.config['init'] or         tools.config['update'], pooljobs=False)
File "workspace/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/pooler.py", line 39, in get_db_and_pool
addons.load_modules(db, force_demo, status, update_module)
File "workspace/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/addons/__init__.py", line 883, in load_modules
processed_modules.extend(load_module_graph(cr, graph, status, report=report,skip_modules=processed_modules))
File "workspace/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/addons/__init__.py", line 748, in load_module_graph
load_init_update_xml(cr, m, idref, mode, kind)
File "workspace/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/addons/__init__.py", line 641, in load_init_update_xml
tools.convert_xml_import(cr, m, fp, idref, mode=mode, **kwargs)
File "workspace/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/tools/convert.py", line 975, in convert_xml_import
obj.parse(doc.getroot())
File "workspace/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/tools/convert.py", line 865, in parse
self._tags[rec.tag](self.cr, rec, n)
File "workspace/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/tools/convert.py", line 826, in _tag_record
f_val = _eval_xml(self,field, self.pool, cr, self.uid, self.idref)
File "workspace/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/tools/convert.py", line 152, in _eval_xml
idref)
File "workspace/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/tools/convert.py", line 146, in _process
idref[id]=self.id_get(cr, id)
File "workspace/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/tools/convert.py", line 842, in id_get
res = self.model_id_get(cr, id_str)
File "workspace/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/tools/convert.py", line 851, in model_id_get
return model_data_obj.get_object_reference(cr, self.uid, mod, id_str)
File "workspace/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/tools/misc.py", line 823, in cached_result
result2 = fn(self2, cr, *args[:self.skiparg-2], **kwargs2)
File "workspace/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 609, in get_object_reference
data_id = self._get_id(cr, uid, module, xml_id)
File "workspace/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/tools/misc.py", line 823, in cached_result
result2 = fn(self2, cr, *args[:self.skiparg-2], **kwargs2)
File "workspace/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 602, in _get_id
raise ValueError('No references to %s.%s' % (module, xml_id))
ValueError: No references to stock.report_picking_list
```

Comment: On looking at the trace-back it looks that its trying to search an `xml_id = 'report_picking_list'` in the stock module. Pls check if such an id is present in the module.
Also if your problem is not resolved then pasting the code might help me understand the problem in more detail. cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your trace-back that menu with the XML Identifier `report_picking_list` is missing in your code, if you are p;laying with code you may have deleted it, I have added refernce code where you can find it.

```
./stock/stock_report.xml:5:        
         <report id="report_picking_list" model="stock.picking" name="stock.picking.list" string="Packing list" rml="stock/report/picking.rml"/>
```

If you are facing this problem in single db that means you have deleted the record with same identifier, so in `ir_model_data` you can add this named record so their will be reference to fix it.  Or Else Check with New db if it occur on all db means your code has been tampered So you cna recheck your code.

Regards.

Comment: yes sir i checked the report rml of stock that line is present but a tricky thing happens is when i search for the content 'report_picking_list' in the addons its not listing the stock_report.xml file

Answer (score 3):

As per the error it seems your report tag might be removed from `report.xml`.
write this tag in `stock/stock_report.xml`:

```
  <report id="report_picking_list" model="stock.picking" name="stock.picking.list" string="Packing list" rml="stock/report/picking.rml"/>
```

then update stock module. I am sure you will not get this error again.